# AFNetworking + expected identifer or '('

Tags: ios, afnetworking, cocoapods

I am using cocoapods for AFNetworking. I am using AFNetworking v2.6.1. XCode 7.3.1, OSX 10.11.4.

I am getting following error while compilation:
AFHTTPRequestOperation.h (this file contains following line only)
`../../../AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperation.h` -> Expected Identifier or '('

Even the same for ZXBitArray.h (this file contains following line only)
`../../../ZXingObjC/ZXingObjC/common/ZXBitArray.h`   -> Expected Identifier or '('

I am completely confused with whats happening here.

Comment: post your code with yout ques.

Comment: Note, sometimes these weird error messages can show up if you have an earlier `include` that has mismatched braces, parentheses or, if using Objective-C, it is missing a `@end`. If you change the order of your `import` statements and you get a similarly cryptic error but in a different place, that's a good way to confirm that one of your headers (usually the one immediately preceding the one with the error) might have some imbalanced braces/parentheses/etc. You might also want to do "Project" - "Clean" and then rebuild again.